# Karate UI and Gatling

Tags: karate

I am trying to execute gatling performance test using a Karate UI feature where the AUT is an angular application and is protected by siteminder. I am able to execute the tests from gatling, but I am getting an error that requests were not sent when they clearly are. I do have experience testing APIs with karate and gatling. Has anyone done this with success?